# How to extract specific elements from XML node

Tags: r, xml

I have something like this:

```
<ValuesPeaks>
  <Peak Start="244" Stop="248" Max="245" XValue="149" YValue="100.0000"/>
  <Peak Start="361" Stop="368" Max="366" XValue="173.2" YValue="96.2713"/>
<ValuesPeaks>
```

Except they are a lot longer and I have about 300 sets of `<ValuesPeaks>`. How can I extract only the XValue and YValue elements of everything? I thought I can do `xpathSApply('//ValuesPeaks[XValue]',xmlValue)`, but its not working. I then thought I can do `toString.XMLNode()` then use `regexpr()` and `substr()` to obtain what I want but that seems inefficient. I think I'm missing something. Please share your expertise. Thanks.

```
p<-list.files()[[1]]
library(XML)
x<-xmlParse(p)
getNodeSet(x,'//Data/RESULT/*/*/*/ValuesPeaks/Peak')
f<-xpathSApply(x,'//Data/RESULT/*/*/*/ValuesPeaks/Peak')
t<-toString.XMLNode(f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to extract those attributes. It all depends on what you want the result to look like. Here are a couple of examples.

The first uses `xmlAttrs()` and subsets the results.

```
xpathApply(doc, "//ValuesPeaks//*", function(x) xmlAttrs(x)[c("XValue", "YValue")])
# [[1]]
#     XValue     YValue 
#      "149" "100.0000" 
#
# [[2]]
#    XValue    YValue 
#   "173.2" "96.2713"
```

The second is likely more efficient. It uses an XPath statement to get the two relevant attributes.

```
xpathSApply(doc, "//ValuesPeaks//@*[name()='XValue' or name()='YValue']")
#    XValue     YValue     XValue     YValue 
#     "149" "100.0000"    "173.2"  "96.2713"
```

You could even do

```
sapply(unname(xmlToList(doc)), "[", c("XValue", "YValue"))
#        [,1]       [,2]     
# XValue "149"      "173.2"  
# YValue "100.0000" "96.2713"
```

Data:

```
txt <- '<ValuesPeaks>
  <Peak Start="244" Stop="248" Max="245" XValue="149" YValue="100.0000"/>
  <Peak Start="361" Stop="368" Max="366" XValue="173.2" YValue="96.2713"/>
</ValuesPeaks>'
library(XML)
doc <- xmlParse(txt)
```

Comment: great answer Rich, thanks. Would there be a way to maintain each set separately? Out of the options you provided, I like the first one, however it lists each one individually, but the data has 300 sets of these X/Y values, is there a way to generate each set's values?

Comment: @SpencerTrinh - This should work for all nodes named `ValuesPeaks`. The preceeding `//` takes care of that.

Answer (score 2):

Your XML is malformed (the second `ValuePeaks` tag needs a `/` to make it a closing tag), which causes `xml2::read_xml` to complain. `read_html` actually automatically fixes it though, so you can do

```r
library(xml2)
library(tidyverse)

x <- '<ValuesPeaks>
  <Peak Start="244" Stop="248" Max="245" XValue="149" YValue="100.0000"/>
  <Peak Start="361" Stop="368" Max="366" XValue="173.2" YValue="96.2713"/>
<ValuesPeaks>' 

df <- x %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    xml_find_all('//peak') %>% {
        data_frame(xvalue = xml_attr(., 'xvalue'), 
                   yvalue = xml_attr(., 'yvalue'))
    } %>% 
    type_convert()

df
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   xvalue   yvalue
#>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1  149.0 100.0000
#> 2  173.2  96.2713
```